# How to add blanks for missing data after fetching data from nseindia.com

Tags: python-3.x

[NIFTY option chain for expiry: 01-Oct-2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmUaL.png)

The image above sums up the problem I am facing. The json file fetched has NO data at 13050 strike on the CE side. I am ok with not having data but I want to still see that strike in strike column with a blank row or 0 values for it on the respective side. JSON file has data for ALL the expiry dates possible.
[JSON data file if needed:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z0Va8obzvW29ZlYdrAljFgdUlUlqT4qy/view?usp=sharing)

The sample code (which won't work for you guys goes something like this:)

```
r = session.get(url, headers = url_headers).json()
        with open('oidata.json', 'w') as files:
            files.write(json.dumps(r, indent = 4, sort_keys= True ))# writing data in json file jsut for for reference 

expiry_dates = r['records']['expiryDates'] 

# storing ONLY the data for given expiry
#Assume that we have at least one of the values for user or default expiry

if user_expiry in expiry_dates:
        print('Using user Expiry: ', user_expiry)
        ce_values = [items['CE'] for items in r['records']['data'] if 'CE' in items and user_expiry in items['CE']['expiryDate']]
        pe_values = [items['PE'] for items in r['records']['data'] if 'PE' in items and user_expiry in items['PE']['expiryDate']]
else:
        print('Using Default Expiry: ', default_expiry)
        ce_values = [items['CE'] for items in r['records']['data'] if 'CE' in items and default_expiry in items['CE']['expiryDate']]
        pe_values = [items['PE'] for items in r['records']['data'] if 'PE' in items and default_expiry in items['PE']['expiryDate']]
```

So, how do I add the blank row for missing data and align my strikes for both CE and PE, so that I can only have 1 STRIKE column???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you make `ce_values` and `pe_values` into two dataframes, you can merge the two dataframe on `strikePrice` as follows

```
ce=pd.DataFrame(ce_values) 
pe=pd.DataFrame(pe_values)

df=ce.merge(pe,on='strikePrice', how='outer', suffixes=["_ce","_pe"])
```

This will align both the dataframe on 'strikePrice' with an empty row where a ce or pe value is missing.

Let me know if this is what you are expecting.

Comment: Hey man, Your assumption is correct after the code mentioned above I have 2 dataframes with names: ce_data_final and pe_data_final
after looking at yoyr suggestion I added following code line after sorting dropping and rearranging my data.

df=ce_data_final.merge(pe_data_final,on='strikePrice', how='outer', suffixes=c("_ce","_pe"))

now the problem is, I do not understand what suffixes is doing here... so I am getting error saying: name 'c' is not defined

sorry for that, but could you please explain what do I do here??

Comment: Were you able to get the output that you wanted?

Comment: yes I got the output if I changed above line to:

@Hasanb

df=ce_data_final.merge(pe_data_final,on='strikePrice', how='outer', suffixes=("_ce","_pe"))

but there is 1 problem that 1 strike is getting ommited in sorting and is written on the last row on the PE side...also not able understand the purpose of 'c' in 'suffixes = c("_ce", "_pe")

Comment: got everything running and sorted 'df' wrt 'strikePrice' and got the desired result, but still getting error for line....................:

df=ce_data_final.merge(pe_data_final,on='strikePrice', how='outer', suffixes=c("_ce_final_data","_pe_final_data"))
df = df.sort_values(['strikePrice'])
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
df=ce_data_final.merge(pe_data_final,on='strikePrice', how='outer', suffixes=c("_ce_final_data","_pe_final_data"))
NameError: name 'c' is not defined

Comment: i'm sorry, i am modifying the code in above answer. A small confusion between R and python programming. :P

Comment: Yes, after sorting and changing code, I got the result I wanted.

Comment: Glad to know. Have a nice day :)